# Having trouble parsing XML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery

I'm trying to parse some XML data using jQuery, and as it stands I have extracted the 'ID' attribute of the required nodes and stored them in an array, and now I want to run a loop for each array member and eventually grab more attributes from the notes specific to each ID.

The problem currently is that once I get to the 'for' loop, it isn't looping, and I think I may have written the xml path data incorrectly. It runs once and I recieve the 'alert(arrayIds.length);' only once, and it only loops the correct amount of times if I remove the subsequent xml path code.

Here is my function:

```
    var arrayIds = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "question.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml)
    {
                  $(xml).find("C").each(function(){
                        $("#attr2").append($(this).attr('ID') + "<br />");
                        arrayIds.push($(this).attr('ID'));
                  });

                  for (i=0; i<arrayIds.length; i++)
                  {
                    alert(arrayIds.length);
                    $(xml).find("C[ID='arrayIds[i]']").(function(){
                        // pass values
                        alert('test');
                    });
                  }
    }
  });
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is invalid. You're missing a function name. This is crashing the script.

```
$(xml).find("C[ID='arrayIds[i]']").(function(){
```

should be (perhaps):

```
$(xml).find("C[ID='" + arrayIds[i] + "']").each(function(){ // Note the added each
```

Comment: Your suggestion did cause the 'alert(arrayIds.length);' to loop and run the correct number of times, however the 'alert('test');' inside the inner function did not execute for some reason.

Comment: Matthews latest version seemed to fixed the problem. Thanks very much for your help also though.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I tested a slight older version of your post. Your fix works correctly (as I'm sure you know).

Both fixes solve the original, however Matthews post causes the second alert to run a large amount of times due the '*' replacing the 'C' in the XML Path.

The behaviour caused by the '*' I do not fully understand but it seemed incorrect.

Comment: @Jack - `*` is a wildcard selector, for HTML anyway. The reason I didn't concatenate the `arrayIds[i]` in my original answer, was that Matthew did in his, and I didn't want it to seem as though I was copying from his answer, so I referenced his. Then he changed his answer to take from mine the actual cause of the crash, so I updated mine in response.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
$(xml).find("*[ID=" + arrayIds[i] + "]").each(function(){
    // pass values
    alert('test');
});
```

Before you were looking for an id with the literal value "arrayIds[i]".  Also, ids are unique, so you don't need the C, and I changed it to standard jQuery syntax.  Also, as Patrick said, you were missing each.

Comment: After ammending my code to your suggestion, there was no change in behaviour and my Error Console prompted me with 'XML filter is applied to non-XML value...'.

ADDED: I have added the 'each', which again like Patrick's answer causes the loop to function correctly, however I still have trouble executing the function inside the loop to trigger the second alert.

Any ideas?
I'm not personally familiar with this error.

Comment: `'#'+arrayIds[i]` relies on the parser knowing that the attribute called `ID` is supposed to be of schema type `ID`. For HTML documents that will be the case, but for XML it will (usually) not. The `[ID=...]` attribute selector *is* necessary.

Comment: Your latest update seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks to everyone who commented for the help.